# Enabling libmp3lame for FFMPEG on elastic beanstalk

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lamemp3

I am trying to enable libmp3lame with FFMPEG in elastic beanstalk (Amazon Redhat Linux machine).

I am able to successfully install FFMPEG in `/ffmpeg.config` with the following script:

```
# .ebextensions/ffmpeg.config

packages:
  yum:
    autoconf: []
    automake: []
    cmake: []
    freetype-devel: []
    gcc: []
    gcc-c++: []
    git: []
    libtool: []
    make: []
    nasm: []
    pkgconfig: []
    zlib-devel: []
sources:
  /usr/local/src: http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.2.tar.bz2
commands:
  ffmpeg_install:
      cwd: /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-3.2
      command: sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install
```

I need to install libmp3lame however. I've tried to do this with an `--enable-libmp3lame` flag and the directions [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos#FFmpeg). The modified script:

```
packages:
yum:
    autoconf: []
    automake: []
    cmake: []
    freetype-devel: []
    gcc: []
    gcc-c++: []
    git: []
    libtool: []
    make: []
    nasm: []
    pkgconfig: []
    zlib-devel: []
sources:
  /usr/local/src: http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.2.tar.bz2
commands:
  01-install_libmp3lame:
      cwd: /usr/local/src/
      command: curl -L -O http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lame/lame/3.99/lame-3.99.5.tar.gz && tar xzvf lame-3.99.5.tar.gz && cd lame-3.99.5 && ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --disable-shared --enable-nasm && make && make install
  02-ffmpeg_install:
      cwd: /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-3.2
      command: sudo ./configure --enable-libmp3lame && --prefix=/usr && make && make install
```

This doesn't work. Command `01-install_libmp3lame` completes. Command 02-ffmpeg_install fails because:

```
[2017-10-12T20:55:19.324Z] INFO  [24606] - [Application update app-8fe3-123456_7895@111/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/prebuild_3_clover_platform/Command 02-ffmpeg_install] : Activity execution failed, because: ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found
```

I have tried installing libmp3lame in /ffmpeg-3.2 and got the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You used `--prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build"`, but you didn't tell ffmpeg to look there for it. You can omit this and it will probably use `/usr/local/` by default.
2. You are trying to run `--prefix=/usr` as an independent command instead of part of your ffmpeg `./configure`. You can omit this.
3. If you're going to use a release branch of ffmpeg instead of the git snapshot you should use the latest version which is currently 3.3, not 3.2. However, 3.4 is due very soon (within days or a week I'm guessing).
4. No need for `sudo` to configure, but you may need it for `make install` depending on your system and user.

Below are commands you can adapt. I didn't verify the paths are correct to the directories containing the source for lame and ffmpeg.

```
cd lame-3.99.5
make uninstall
make distclean
./configure --disable-shared --enable-nasm
make
make install
cd ../ffmpeg
make uninstall
cd ../
rm -f ffmpeg
curl -O http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.3.4.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-libmp3lame
make
make install
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.